# `ControlCommand` not working with `ComboLBox`

Tags: autoit

Instead of returning the currect selected font, it returns 0.

```vb
ShellExecute("notepad.exe")
WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad")
Send("!O")
Send("F")
WinWaitActive("Font")
$select = ControlCommand("Font", "", "[CLASS:ComboLBox; INSTANCE:1]", "GetCurrentSelection", "")
MsgBox(0,"", $select)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That control is actually a "Combo **L** Box", not a ComboBox. As the AutoIt helpfile says under `ControlCommand`:

> Certain commands that work on normal Combo and ListBoxes do not work
>   on "ComboLBox" controls.

The ComboLBox is actually a child control of the ComboBox, and is just the drop down part of it. If you use a more advanced window finder like Spy++, you will actually see there is a ComboBox there, with two children (an Edit and the ComboLBox). So your code will work if you change `"[CLASS:ComboLBox; INSTANCE:1]"` to `"[CLASS:ComboBox; INSTANCE:1]"`.

Furthermore, you can improve your code for triggering the menu item, so that the entire operation can be done in the background.

```
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <WinAPI.au3>

Local $IDM_FONT = 33
Local $hWindow = WinGetHandle("Untitled - Notepad")

_WinAPI_PostMessage($hWindow, $WM_COMMAND, $IDM_FONT, 0)

Local $hFontWin = WinWait("Font")
$select = ControlCommand($hFontWin, "", "ComboBox1", "GetCurrentSelection", "")
WinClose($hFontWin)

MsgBox(0,"", $select)
```

Alternatively, you can interact with the ComboLBox in the same way you would a listbox:

```
$hLBox = ControlGetHandle($hFontWin, "", "ComboLBox1")
$itemIndex = _GUICtrlListBox_GetCurSel()
$select = _GUICtrlListBox_GetText($hLBox, $itemIndex)
```

Why `ControlCommand` doesn't work with this particular type of list box I have no idea. I can only guess that internally they check the control class against "ComboBox" and "ListBox" and return zero if there is no match.

Comment: Thanks for the great hint with Spy++! That means, the ComboLBox is actually a *Combo List Box*...

Comment: @JohannesThomasMeyer, exactly. You don't usually see it because not many people make use of `CBS_SIMPLE` style combo boxes. In fact I'm going to edit the answer to show that you can use `GUIListbox.au3` to read it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Matt. How can I find other IDM* for specific menu item control like file save etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ControlGetText()](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlGetText.htm) to read the name of the currently active font, if this is what you want to accomplish.

```
ShellExecute("notepad.exe")
WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad")
Send("!O")
Send("F")
WinWaitActive("Font")
$select = ControlGetText("Font", "", "Edit1")
MsgBox(0,"", $select)
```